# Step wizard in Asp.Net MVC unintentionally validating with prev button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-validate

I'm following this guide [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/9a5fe277-6e7e-43e5-8408-a28ff5be7801.aspx) to create a step wizard to traverse multiple pages with forms on each while saving each forms data to store in my db but the problem I'm having is on the second page 'addressDetails'. When I press the prevBtn to return to the previous page 'basicDetails', my form is trying to do client side validation and I get all the validation errors instead of posting to my action method to see whether the prevBtn or nextBtn was pressed

Here is my addressDetails page

```html
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("AddressDetails", "User", FormMethod.Post)) {
  <div class="row">
    <h3>What's the address for this payout method?</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="AddressLine1">Street address</label> 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine1, new { @id = "AddressLine1", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 123 Main St." }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine1,
      "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="AddressLine2">Apt, suite, bldg. (optional)</label> 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine2, new { @id = "AddressLine2", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. Apt #6" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine2,
      "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 5px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="City">City</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @id = "City", @class = "form-control input-lg" }) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 0px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="State">State / Province</label> 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateCode, new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @id = "State", @class = "btn-group-lg countryList form-control selectpicker" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m
        => m.StateCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PostalCode">Zip code / Postal code</label> 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode, new { @id = "PostalCode", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 94102" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PostalCode, "", new { @class =
      "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "Country", @class = "btn-group-lg countryList form-control selectpicker" })
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <hr />
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="submit" name="prevBtn" value='Previous' />
      <input type="submit" name="nextBtn" value='Next' />
    </div>

  </div>
  }
</div>
```

Here is my action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressDetails(UserAddressViewModel addressViewModel, string prevBtn, string nextBtn)
    {

        YogaProfileBankAccount obj = GetBankAccount();

        if (prevBtn != null)
        {
            UserBillingViewModel billingViewModel = new UserBillingViewModel();
            //bd.CustomerID = obj.CustomerID;
            //bd.CompanyName = obj.CompanyName;

            return View("BasicDetails", billingViewModel);
        }

        if (nextBtn != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //obj.Address = data.Address;
                //obj.City = data.City;
                //obj.Country = data.Country;
                //obj.PostalCode = data.PostalCode;

                return View("AccountDetails");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

So here is what happens when I press previous, all the fields try to get validated

[image]